# remove table rows except the first one

Tags: android

```
public void populate() {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());

        tr.setId(100 + count);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        Button b_add = new Button(getActivity());
        b_add.setId(20);
        b_add.setText("+");
        b_add.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        b_add.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        b_add.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        b_add.setOnClickListener(add);

        tr.addView(b_add);

        TextView v_no = new EditText(getActivity());
        v_no.setId(200 + count);
        v_no.setHint("Vehicale NO");
        v_no.setTag("adress");
        v_no.setTag("v_no");
        v_no.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        v_no.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tr.addView(v_no);

        Button b_minus = new Button(getActivity());
        b_minus.setId(20);
        b_minus.setText("-");
        b_minus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        b_minus.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        b_minus.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        b_minus.setOnClickListener(remove);
        tr.addView(b_minus);
        // finally add this to the table row
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        count++;
    }
```

I create this code to create a table with  three columns using table layout.It works fine.But I need to remove the table rows except the first row.Can u help me to do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while (yourTableLayout.getChildCount() > 1)
  yourTableLayout.removeView(yourTableLayout.getChildAt(yourTableLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
```

This should iterate over your `TableLayout` and remove the rows one by one from the bottom to the top, until there remains just one (which won't get removed).